# How to denote the zero matrix of any order without specifying its order?

Tags: matrices, notation

I want to consider a zero matrix of any order and i do not want to specify the order of that matrix so as to make it satisfies my requirements. Will the notation $(0)$ or $[0]$ work? Or, is there any other appropriate notations?

Comment: Just write $0$. It will be clear from the context. You can use boldface if you really want to distinguish it from a scalar.

Comment: Usually, $0$ is used. Nevertheless, I'm not sure if not mentioning the dimension on purpose is a good thing. It probably depends on the context, but usually, giving the dimensions of objects is a good practice (and is very useful to the reader).

Comment: I usually use $\rm O$.

Answer (score 1):

Typically one would use $\mathbf{0}$ to denote the zero matrix, or the zero vector depending on context. Should the need for both arise, one can denote the zero vector by $\mathbf{\underline{0}}$. Needless to say this is somewhat dependant on preferance, so what is important is to eliminate possible confusion - generally speaking the context is enough.

As a side note, further adding upon what @Surb said, ideally one would denote the zero matrix by $\left[0\right]_{n \times n}$, but if you don't want to write the dimension the notation mentioned above is acceptable.